# How can i display a view with annotations

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, controller

Normally i used to display my views in javaee with the "normal" kind of servlet like this :

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/myview.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

But i'm on a project where there is only annotation everywhere and i don't understand how can i display some view this way ...

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/user")
@Produces("application/json")
public class UserController extends Controller{

    @Path("v1/{pseudo}")
    @GET
    public String getUser(@PathParam("pseudo") String pseudo){
    ...
```

Can someone help me ?

Thx

Comment: Its a restful webservice, so you should read up on that. For that matter you could call it from your servlet. Or inject it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my google searsh was bad and i found my finnaly answer :
    @Path("/documentation")
    public class DocumentationController extends HttpServlet{

```
    @GET
    public void getHome(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                        @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/test.jsp")
                .forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

thx for the response anyway